# Injecting a type conversion factory with autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm trying to get rid of a service locator pattern in an application using Autofac. Currently, I have a class like this:

```
class Factory {
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;
    public Factory(ILifetimeScope scope) {
        _scope = scope;
    }
    public Operation CreateOperation(OperationData dto) {
        var destinationType = NameConventionLookup(dto.GetType().Name);
        return _scope.Resolve(destinationType, new TypedParameter(dto.GetType(), dto));
    }
    private Type NameConventionLookup(Type t) {
        // Return a type by removing parts of the type name and appending others
    }
}
```

Basically, I get a poco object, and based on this object I create another object with the input as constructor argument. Example types:

```
class MyDto : OperationData {
    public string Foo;
    public int Bar;
}
class MyOperation : Operation {
    public MyOperation(MyDto dto) { ... }
}
```

Can I get rid of the `ILifetimeScope` in the factory? I would like to instead get some factory method, `Func<OperationData, Operation>` or the like, but can Autofac generate this? Can I help the library so that it can?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `Factory` class is defined inside the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) there is no reason to remove the reference to `ILifetimeScope` since in that case is not the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), but [merely mechanics](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/).